# Laravel 5.3 Different Workspaces

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.3. I have a company registration and then the company invites employees. The objective is that each company and its employees work on a unique "workspace". 
An example would be Company Zeus has it's employees Hercules and Megara. When either Hercules or Megara login, they would go to the workspace "Olympus" where they would view different information pulled from several API's.

I'm kind of confused on how to proceed to accomplish this. Anybody can give me some guidance?

To add to the example, a company Odin has an employee Thor. When Thor logins, he will go to the workspace "Valhalla". But all of it on the same application.

EDIT: I've easily done the registration part and inviting users. My question is, how do I structure my app so that it presents different workspaces depending on the logged in employee?

EDIT2: To give a more real life example, it's basically what Slack has with the teams(but in my case there will only be one "team" for each company) or Podio.

Comment: So what would be the questions here? You can have in the company table the "workspace name" because it's a 1-1 relation and you know the company of a given user

Comment: Does this mean Thor will die when he logs in? Sorry, couldn't resist ;P

Comment: @ka_lin I have a workspace table, a company table and an employee table. See my EDIT to check the actual question.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob nice one xDD

Comment: Have you set up Laravel's Authentication? ([Laravel Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication))

Comment: @MihailoMisic Yes, I set it up with the `make:auth` command.

Comment: Ok so the first solution that comes to mind is that each workspace could be presented as a diffrent blade template, or at the very least diffrent layout / partial. So when you're logging in the user (`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`) check which company she/he belongs to and redirect to the corresponding template.

Comment: Depending on how much separation you need between workspaces (different look/data vs completely different experience) I'd either go with the suggestion from @MihailoMisic or do the same kind of thing with a controller. The blade method could be as simple as `@extends('layouts.'.$company.'.application');`

Comment: Having a blade for each company seems like the easiest road to take, but, and I'm just letting my imagination run wild here, if the App has 1000 companies, I think it's ineficient to have 1000 blade templates. Basically the only thing different between each companies workspace is the data. The layout will stay the same. I was thinking and I think the best way is to put most of the app working dynamically, so depending on the company it displays the data onto the main blade template.

Comment: Do you still have a question?

Comment: @tam No, since I am still trying to work on the idea in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look into **multi-tenancy**.

The best suggestion for Laravel would probably be something like:

https://tenancy.dev/

There is also this really simple approach although might be too simple for some circumstances:

https://laraveldaily.com/simple-laravel-multi-tenancy-with-single-trait/

As for the invitations, I have used this package previously which worked great:

https://packagist.org/packages/junaidnasir/larainvite

Best of luck with your project.